# Android how to proper overlay image to support multiple screen

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, overlay, margin

I was able to overlay an image in the table layout, but the design will be run in multiple size of screen. Because i'm using margin to achieve the effect of overlay. Below is the code. Is there any suggestion that i can achieve the desired result? Thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ads_body"
                        android:stretchColumns="*">


                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.10"
                            android:gravity="center"

                            >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/button"
                                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="260dp" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="50dp">


                            </View>


                        </TableRow>


                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.20"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/scoreboard_avatar_how_to_earn_point"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />


                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.20"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/scoreboard_avatar_how_to_earn_point"

                                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey" />


                        </TableRow>


                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.1">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:background="@drawable/ads_table_border"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp">


                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/scoreboard_point"
                                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                                    android:src="@drawable/scoreboard_point" />


                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:background="@drawable/ads_table_border"

                                android:paddingTop="5dp">


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ads_point"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                                    android:text="@string/scoreboard_point"
                                    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </RelativeLayout>


                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:background="@drawable/ads_table_border"

                                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/scoreboard_coin"
                                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                                    android:layout_height="25dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:src="@drawable/dibs_scoreboard_coin" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                          android:background="@drawable/ads_table_border"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ads_coin"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                   android:text="@string/scoreboard_coin"
                                    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                        </TableRow>


                    </TableLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>


            </FrameLayout>


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="-150dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/head_female_1_circle"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ifc_reward"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/hero_chamber_city_line"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ads_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create folders and xml files for different screen sizes:

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

If that doesn't help try getting screen size from Java code and then setting margins programatically.

Comment: Is this the effective way to create layout? Because as i know, if i want to modify the design, i need to edit all of the xml.

Comment: That is the best way, based on my experience.